How is this conditional expectation been calculated?
I am reading a paper by Baron and Besanko (1987) (https://www.jstor.org/stable/2555639) and I am having a trouble in understanding a particular portion of their math that deals with conditional expectations. Any help is deeply appreciated!
C is the cost function: $C = c(\theta,a)x + k + \sqrt{\alpha\epsilon}$ where "epsilon is the realised value of $\tilde \epsilon$ with mean 0"
$z=C + \sqrt{\beta\eta}$  ($\beta$ is the randomness parameter, "$\eta$ is the realised value of $\tilde \eta$ with mean 0")
$\alpha>0 \beta>0$
They write:
For the case where $\tilde \epsilon$ and $\tilde\eta$ are standard normal, independent random variables, conditional distribution of of cost conditional on z can be written as:
$g(C|z) = N(C|(c(\theta,a)x + k)\frac{\beta}{\alpha+\beta} + z \frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta},\frac{\alpha\beta}{\alpha+\beta})$
where N(.|m,v) denotes normal density function with mean m and variance v.
so, if I am not mistaken, they mean that $E[C|z] =(c(\theta,a)x + k)\frac{\beta}{\alpha+\beta} + z \frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}$ and $Var[C|z] =\frac{\alpha\beta}{\alpha+\beta}$.
I don't understand how have they calculated this mean and variance. Any help is deeply appreciated. I am absolutely lost here.
